# How to select <td> of the <table> with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html-table, parent-child

I know this is very easy question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Only answers are the ones using jQuery, not pure JS. I've tried the code below and it doesn't work. I don't know why.

```
var t = document.getElementById("table"),
    d = t.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
    r = d.getElementsByTagName("td");
```

This also doesn't work:

```
var t = document.getElementById("table"),
    d = t.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
    r = d.childNodes;
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the best way to do this?

EDIT:
I indeed have the id of my table table. Preety silly I know. This is how my HTML looks:

```
<table id="table">
            <tr>
                <td id="c1">1</td>
                <td id="c2">2</td>
                <td id="c3">3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="b1">4</td>
                <td id="b2">5</td>
                <td id="b3">6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="a1">7</td>
                <td id="a2">8</td>
                <td id="a3">9</td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

To explain my intentions more clearly > I wish to make a tic tac toe game. For starters, I wish to click on the < td > and be able extract the id of that particular < td >. How to do it most efficiently?

Comment: The best way is to use a library, like jQuery

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Do you really have a `<table>` element with "table" as its "id" attribute?

Comment: @Shvelo `Only answers are the ones using jQuery` - he's looking for something that's just pure JavaScript.

Comment: Could you define "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This `d = t.getElementsByTagName("tr")` and this `r = d.getElementsByTagName("td")` are both `arrays`. The `getElementsByTagName` returns an collection of elements even if there's just one found on your match.

So you have to use like this:

```
var t = document.getElementById("table"), // This have to be the ID of your table, not the tag
    d = t.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0],
    r = d.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
```

Place the index of the array as you want to access the objects.

Note that `getElementById` as the name says just get the element with matched id, so your table have to be like `<table id='table'>` and `getElementsByTagName` gets by the tag.

**EDIT:**

Well, continuing this post, I think you can do this:

```
var t = document.getElementById("table");
var trs = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var tds = null;

for (var i=0; i<trs.length; i++)
{
    tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var n=0; n<tds.length;n++)
    {
        tds[n].onclick=function() { alert(this.innerHTML); }
    }
}
```

Try it!

Comment: +1, but don't **fully** like this, because there can be more than one `tr` and more than one `td`

Comment: To be pedantic, they're not true arrays, but `NodeList`s.

Comment: @MikeStewart of course, this is for he learn how it works, then he apply a loop or whatever he needs.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that those are arrays, I didn't know that. I have now edited the question with a bit more specificity. Is the answer here more appropriate or should I make another question regarding the tic tac toe part? :)

Comment: @Márcio This is a stunning answer, exactly what I was looking for.
I have a few questions regarding your solution because I would like to know the thought process behind it :)
1.Why did you use the for loops?
2. How come .onclick is triggered? It confuses me because .onclick is deep within the for loops. How does it know wich trd[n] I am clicking on?

Comment: @oFca 1.So you have one array with all `tr` objects of the table and you need to loop them to reach the all `td` on each `tr`, this is the first loop. So to each `tr` you'll have another array of objects(`tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");`) that carries the `td`s, it's the secund loop. So within the secund loop `i` corresponds to the index of the current `tr` and `n` the index of the current `td`, then `tds[n]` is your current `td`.2.When you set the `onclick` to it, browser will now handle the event for this object. The event's on 2º loop cause there you have the `td`. Hope it's clear.

Comment: second loop should be tds.length not trs.length

Comment: Don't use this solution, just use a query selector for this and loop on the result. Like @Joe told before: you can have more tr than td or more td than tr.

Comment: They are not arrays. They are HTMLCollections. You can iterate through them like arrays and they have indexes but you can't use Array methods, you would need to convert them first.

Answer (score 20):

try `document.querySelectorAll("#table td");`

Comment: This is by far the best solution. Use this answer then loop on result.

Answer (score 3):

```
var t = document.getElementById("table"),
    d = t.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
    r = d.getElementsByTagName("td");
```

needs to be:

```
var t = document.getElementById("table"),
    tableRows = t.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
    r = [], i, len, tds, j, jlen;

for ( i =0, len = tableRows.length; i<len; i++) {
    tds = tableRows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    for( j = 0, jlen = tds.length; j < jlen; j++) {
        r.push(tds[j]);
    }
}
```

Because `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` an Array-like structure. So you need to loop through the return nodes and then populate you `r` like above.

Answer (score 3):

There are also the `rows` and `cells` members;

```
var t = document.getElementById("tbl");
for (var r = 0; r < t.rows.length; r++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < t.rows[r].cells.length; c++) {
        alert(t.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML)
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the first thing that actually worked, thanks. I did "t.rows[r].cells[c].parentElement.style.display = "none";"  and it referensed the parent object.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this, and this is but one of them.

```
$("table").find("tbody td").eq(0).children().first()
```

Answer (score 2):

There begin to appear some answers that assume you want to get all `<td>` elements from `#table`. If so, the simplest cross-browser way how to do this is `document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('td')`. This works because `getElementsByTagName` doesn't return only immediate children. No loops are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can select your table using the ID you defined and then select all child elements with the tag tr or td as you wish.

```
let myTable = document.querySelector("#table");
let allTds = myTable.querySelectorAll("td");
let allTrs = myTable.querySelectorAll("tr");
```

Then you can do what every you want with it. There is a list of functions you can apply to them here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/entries

for example iterate through them and log the content like this:

```
for (item of allTds.values()){
    console.log(item.textContent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Array.from ES6 feature that converts array-like structures (like HTMLCollection) into vanilla arrays and iterate through them your way.

```js
const values = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#table tr td'))
              .map(td => td.innerHTML);

console.log(values) // [1, 2, 3 ... 9]
```

```html
<table id="table">
      <tr>
         <td id="c1">1</td>
         <td id="c2">2</td>
         <td id="c3">3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td id="b1">4</td>
         <td id="b2">5</td>
         <td id="b3">6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td id="a1">7</td>
         <td id="a2">8</td>
         <td id="a3">9</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```