# Add 0 on empty td

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble finding a way to add 0 to empty `<td>`'s

In this case I have a table with some empty td's like this:
`<td></td>`.

And the Java script would find those and add a zero. changing to `<td>0</td>`.

Comment: What's the JS you have currently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select <td> of the <table> with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508262/how-to-select-td-of-the-table-with-javascript)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Going off of @user3783243, could you post the JS you're currently using Theo Toke?

Comment: Loop through all the td's. Get the `innerHTML`, test if it's empty, if it is, replace it with `0`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on writing posts that best enable the community to provide you with assistance.  Your question would be aided by including the code you have already, a [mcve], and a clear explanation of the problem you are facing.  The question as currently posted provides too little detail.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

## Here is a HTML and CSS only solution (no Javascript).

**The benefit of not using Javascript:**

1. The Javascript code has to be run after every change to the table. The CSS-only method will always show the 0 in empty cells, and never show the 0 in non-empty cells, no manual updating necessary.
2. The Javascript code changes empty cells to cells that contain "0", meaning that if you appended content to that cell, the 0 would still be there. With the CSS-only method, the "0" is a pseudo-element, and the `td`'s content is still empty. The user sees a 0, but your code sees an empty box :)

### Explanation of the CSS:

A 0 is displayed after any empty `td` in the table with id `tableId`.

### Technical explanation:

The css selector `#tableId tbody td:empty::after` selects the [`after` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) of all empty `td` elements in `tbody` elements in the element with id `tableId`. Then the `content` attribute of these pseudo-elements is set to `0`.

```css
#tableId tbody td:empty::after {
  content: "0";
}
```

```html
<table id="tableId">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Good idea. Note: This will only work on `<td></td>` not on `<td>    </td>`

Comment: Awesome JS-free solution.

Comment: And an excellent example of the under-used `empty` and `after` Pseudo Elements

Answer (score 3):

Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

I also suggest to [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) the contents

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#tableId tbody td").forEach(td => {
  if (td.textContent.trim() === "") td.textContent = 0;
});
```

```html
<table id="tableId">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```