# Why isn't querySelectorAll working with my ID values?

Tags: javascript, html

I use this piece of code for a live searching and for calculate the "Total" :

```
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    var x = [];
    var y = [];
    var $total = 0;
    var inputString = $("#search").val();

    var act = document.getElementById("labdb").value;

    $('td:first-child').parent().show();
    $('td:first-child').parent().addClass("notHide");
    $('td:first-child').parent().removeClass("toHide");

    $var = $('td:first-child').parent('tr:not(:icontains(' + inputString + ')):not(:contains("Total"))');

    $var.hide();
    $var.addClass('toHide');
    $var.removeClass('notHide')

    for (var price of document.querySelectorAll('tr.notHide td.price')) {   
           x.push(parseFloat(price.innerText));
    }
    for (var cantidad of document.querySelectorAll('tr.notHide td.quantity')) {
        y.push(parseFloat(cantidad.innerText));
    }    
    for(var i = 0; i <= x.length-1; i++){
        $total += x[i] * y[i];
        
    }
    document.getElementById("total"+act).innerText = $total.toFixed(2);
});
```

I have various tables, with differents ID's, first is id='0', second is id='1', etc.
I use collapse ('show') or ('hide') for show the selected table with a selector.
So, the problems comes when I try to calculate the "Total", It's calculated with the value of the  class "notHide" and "price/quantity".
And all the tables get this Class, so the price got crazy if there is more than 1 table with "Total"

I KNOW, that I need to specify the ID of the table to work around, but I cant.

I have tested with:

```
var act = document.getElementById("labdb").value;
var actHTML = document.getElementById("labdb");
```

It get the ID from the selected table, and then, in this part of code include it:

```
for (var price of actHTML.document.querySelectorAll('tr.notHide td.price')) {   
       x.push(parseFloat(price.innerText));
}
for (var cantidad of actHTML.document.querySelectorAll('tr.notHide td.quantity')) {
    y.push(parseFloat(cantidad.innerText));
}
```

But that, dont work, Im all the time thinking about other solutions and trying it, but I cant.
Its the final part of that page. Only need to specify the ID of the "Total" calculator.

I had tried to with:

```
for (var price of document.querySelectorAll('#'+act+' tr.notHide td.price')) {   
           x.push(parseFloat(price.innerText));
    }
    for (var cantidad of document.querySelectorAll('#'+act+' tr.notHide td.quantity')) {
        y.push(parseFloat(cantidad.innerText));
    }
```

**For be more specific, I need that document.querySelectorAll('tr.notHide td.quantity') comes from a specific ID. For the rest, works perfectly, inclusive deleting the others tables with the parameter Total**

**EDIT_0:**

I have do that:

```
let myTable = document.querySelector("#"+act);
let all = myTable.querySelectorAll('tr.notHide td.price');

for (var price of all) {
    x.push(parseFloat(price.innerText));
}
for (var cantidad of all) {
    y.push(parseFloat(cantidad.innerText));
}
for (var i = 0; i <= x.length - 1; i++) {
    $total += x[i] * y[i];

}
```

from here: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508262/how-to-select-td-of-the-table-with-javascript)

And that is the console error:

*scripts.js:57 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#0' is not a valid selector.
at changePrice (https://neutrino.ugr.es/js/scripts.js:57:28)
at HTMLSelectElement. (https://neutrino.ugr.es/js/scripts.js:15:5)
at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js:2:43336)
at y.handle (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js:2:41320)*

Comment: You seem to be mixing jQuery and vanilla JS DOM queries, which isn't generally ideal. If you are including jQuery you may as well make use of it for everything.

Comment: @DBS thanks for all! but the error was that querySelectorAll dont works if the ID start with a digit.

Comment: `actHTML.document.querSelectorAll` should not have the `document`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the error. The method `document.querySelectorAll('')` doesn't work if the ID starts with a digit. Like said in [an article on the subject](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes):

> The spec defines identifiers using a token diagram. They may contain
> the symbols from a to z, from A to Z, from 0 to 9, underscores (_),
> hyphens -, non-ASCII symbols or escape sequences for any symbol.
> **They cannot start with a digit, or a hyphen (-) followed by a digit.** Identifiers require at least one symbol (i.e. the empty
> string is not a valid identifier).

This is the final code:

```
$('#search').keyup(function () {

    var inputString = $("#search").val();

    $('td:first-child').parent().show();
    $('td:first-child').parent().addClass("notHide");
    $('td:first-child').parent().removeClass("toHide");

    $var = $('td:first-child').parent('tr:not(:icontains(' + inputString + ')):not(:contains("Total"))');

    $var.hide();
    $var.addClass('toHide');
    $var.removeClass('notHide')

    changePrice();
});

function changePrice() {
    var x = [];
    var y = [];
    var $total = 0;
    var act = document.getElementById("labdb").value;
    actt="t"+act+act;
    //alert(act);

    var myTable = document.querySelector("#"+actt);
    var allx = myTable.querySelectorAll('tr.notHide td.price');
    var ally = myTable.querySelectorAll('tr.notHide td.quantity');
    //alert(all)

    for (var price of allx) {
        x.push(parseFloat(price.innerText));
    }
    for (var cantidad of ally) {
        y.push(parseFloat(cantidad.innerText));
    }
    for (var i = 0; i <= x.length - 1; i++) {
        $total += x[i] * y[i];

    }
    //alert(x.length)
    document.getElementById("total" + act).innerText = $total.toFixed(2);
}
```

I changed the ID to start with a **t**: `actt="t"+act+act;`
*(act+act is because id is 00, not 0)*